# Blog with CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have Posts_controller and I have Comments_controller and their models and views.

Everything is alright, but my question, how can I combine them, so comments would appear in the same page as posts? In CakePHP tutorial they don't do that. I could include, but I don't think it's appropriate. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the short answer to your question:

You need to do a hasMany relation like this: Posts -> HasMany -> Comments

You set that up in your Posts model file. models/Post.php

Then when you run a $this->Post->find(..) - It will return comments for the post. You then use a foreach in the helper to print them out.

```
foreach($post['Comment'] as $comment) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is not short answer to your question. You should read cake manual, [model associations](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1039/Associations-Linking-Models-Together), and especially [HasMany association](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1043/hasMany). If you do the models relation first and then bake your controllers and views, you'll have the comments on the same page as your posts.